# Redirect references to root to current alias instead

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I'm using a local install of Apache 2.2.11 and have set up an alias to a folder above the document root (`alias localhost/fp/ => /www/dirs/friendpages`). I would like to be able to redirect requests to "/favicon.ico" to `localhost/fp/favicon.ico` as opposed to `localhost/favicon.ico` with a .htaccess file in `localhost/fp`. Is this possible and if so, how would I do that?

The reference to favicon.ico, would come from a file such as the following:
`/www/dirs/friendpages/test.htm (localhost/fp/test.htm)` =>

```
<html>
    <head>
          <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    </head>
    <body>
          Page using favicon.ico
    </body>
</html>
```

I have made several attempts using RewriteRule. For example,

```
RewriteRule ^/favicon.ico$ /www/dirs/friendpages/favicon.ico
```

...but have not been able to find a solution. It appears that I'm confused about what exactly *Pattern* is and what *Substitution* should be (given `RewriteRule Pattern Substitution`). I'm especially confused about how I would set up a RewriteRule distinguishing a relative file reference such as the one via the link tag above vs. an absolute one like "localhost/fp/favicon.ico" (the latter obviously not requiring a redirection).

I also enabled rewrite logging using the following in my `httpd.conf` file:

```
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog /logs/rewrite.log
```

...but all I get, when loading the above listed `localhost/fp/test.htm` with the above stated RewriteRule is this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Nov/2011:05:09:51 --0700] [localhost/sid#14f44f8][rid#2619268/initial] (3) [perdir /www/dirs/friendpages/] strip per-dir prefix: /www/dirs/friendpages/test.htm -> test.htm
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Nov/2011:05:09:51 --0700] [localhost/sid#14f44f8][rid#2619268/initial] (3) [perdir /www/dirs/friendpages/] applying pattern '^/favicon.ico$' to uri 'test.htm'
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Nov/2011:05:09:51 --0700] [localhost/sid#14f44f8][rid#2619268/initial] (1) [perdir /www/dirs/friendpages/] pass through /www/dirs/friendpages/test.htm
```

I have discovered that an alternative way (short of hardcoding the appropriate reference itself) to achieve the desired result is to set up a virtual host (as opposed to simply using an alias) but my gut-feeling is that this should also be possible using mod_rewrite and .htaccess... just how?

Comment: Did you mean for `/www/dirs/fp` and `/www/dirs/friendpages` to be the same directory, or are they really different?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Good catch -- there's no /www/dirs/fp, I adjusted my description above to reflect that. Also, there was a second mistake which I corrected: the link tag makes a reference to **/favicon.ico** as opposed to simply favicon.ico.

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule looks fine to me, I'm not sure why it's not working. (You do have `RewriteEngine on`?)

Since /fp is already aliased to /www/dirs/friendpages, maybe you should just adjust your link href instead:

1. Change it to a relative one:

   ```
   <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
   ```

   That will implicitly refer to /fp/favicon.ico.
2. Change it to point explicitly to /fp/favicon.ico:

   ```
   <link href="/fp/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
   ```

Either way, the href will point to /fp/favicon.ico, which will resolve to  /www/dirs/friendpages/favicon.ico.  If the file is there, then you won't need a rewrite rule for it any more.

I agree that a virtual host is way overkill for this problem.  A RewriteRule or correct href should be all you need to get your favicon.

Comment: Thank you for your response! These look like fine solutions, alas, I made a significant mistake in the link tag of test.htm (just corrected it), which changes the problem: the link tag explicitly refers to `/favicon.ico`, which currently dereferences to /www/favicon.ico. So the challenge is to redirect /favicon.ico to /fp/favicon.ico.

Comment: Thanks for your revised response. Adjusting the references is not an option (at least not if I can avoid it, which is what I'm hoping to achieve with mod_rewrite). There's a possibility that the browser cache is at fault. Still, what I don't understand is that `rewrite.log` makes no mention of the reference to /favicon.ico. Loading `localhost/fp/favicon.ico` explicitly loads the appropriate icon. `RewriteEngine` is on, the limited output in `rewrite.log` proves it -- it's a valid point, though.